# Tikz diagram for current sensor measurement

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw something like this, but i don't even know how to say this in english..

Basically, it is for sensing current from a power line. In the figure b is power line, a is representing a current sensor.

How do i draw this with tikz? Thanks for your help.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Welcome! You could define a `pic` for that. And use pins.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/sensor/.style={code={\draw[line cap=rect] (0,-6pt) coordinate(-b)
arc(-90:90:6pt) coordinate (-t); \node[circle,inner sep=2pt,fill,outer sep=0pt] (-c) at (0,0){}; 
}},every pin edge/.style={stealth-,shorten <=1pt}]
 \pic (s){sensor};
 \draw (s-t) -- coordinate[pin=above right:$a$] ++ (0,1) (s-b) -- ++ (0,-1) 
 (s-c) --  coordinate[pin=above left:$b$] ++ (-1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, that  was very helpful, thanks : )

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but too complicated for comment:

Not being familiar with that symbol, I did a little googling.  Hall effect sensor:
[image: hall effect]
Induction sensor: 
[image]

Of course, circuitiz doesn't have them either.